# javascript callback function parameters

Tags: javascript, cordova, parameters, callback

I want to call a callback function using javascript, as you can see from this example code from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#database_size

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
    // this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
    if (!results.rowsAffected) {
        console.log('No rows affected!');
        return false;
    }
    // for an insert statement, this property will return the ID of the last inserted row
    console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
```

The method "queryDB" is called without any parameters, but the function is defined to receive the variable "tx". Coming from PHP, I can't understand how this works, because it does.
Also there is querySuccess which receives 2 parameters and also works.

My problem is that I need to send 1 my own parameter, so I have modified the call for queryDB like this:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(queryDB(myParam), errorCB);
```

and

```
function queryDB(tx, myParam) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM' + myParam, [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
```

But is does not work.

1) How come there are unsent params being received?
2) How can I add my own params without breaking it?

Comment: when you send the `myParam` to `queryDB(myParam)` what error would come?

Comment: I can not tell, because I run in on a device emulator and I have no debug console yet. But JpBaena13 explained why it should not work as expected.

Comment: Parameters in JavaScript are a suggestion, not a mandate. All functions can take any number of arguments (from 0 to 9999 and beyond) regardless of what parameters are declared. You could think of parameters as aliases for index argmuents: `function foo(a,b,c) {...}` is basically equivalent to `function foo(){ var a = arguments[0], b = arguments[1], c = arguments[2]; ...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think I have found the answer.
Reading from here http://theelitist.net/passing-additional-arguments-to-a-callback-function-in-javascript 
I have realised that Dawson Loudon's response was almost complete, but he missed the "tx" variable that should be passed on the first function that calls the 2nd one, that would be:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) { queryDB(tx, myParam); }, errorCB);

function queryDB(tx, myParam) {
    //logic here
}
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.transaction(function() { queryDB(tx, myParam); }, errorCB);

function queryDB(tx, myParam) {
    //logic here
}
```

The transaction function is looking for callback methods which do not include parameters. You can 'hijack' this by assigning an anonymous function that calls the function you want with parameters.

Comment: But I thought that "tx" was the name that the variable received when it was received by the function, but how can I send a variable that does not exists nor was ever created? Thanks!

Comment: That is what I am showing above. You have to pass the tx parameter first, as this is how the transaction functions, by using an anonymous function as the callback you can pass additional parameters with the call (i.e. `queryDB(tx, myParam)`. You have to pass `tx`, but with the method above you can also pass `myParam` or any other parameters you wish to pass.

Comment: But 'tx' is not created ever as OP said.

Comment: yes it is, `db.transaction` automatically passes `tx` to the callback function parameters assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
db.transaction (queryDB, errorCB);
```

you are passing as a parameter the function itself, but if you try this:

```
db.transaction (queryDB(myParam), errorCB);
```

you'd be passing as a parameter the result of the function, which will generate an error.

`db.transacción` receives parameter are 2 functions, If you need to pass custom parameter simply write them in the declaration

```
function queryDB(tx, myParam) {
    //Using your myParam
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
...
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
```

Remember that javascript is an interpreted programming language and is not object-oriented

Comment: Wouldn't myParam be undefined within the scope of function queryBD?